# Binary Search Tree(BST)

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

Hi everybody I make  logical mistake but I dont find mistake .

thank you :))

My algorithm

```
#include <iostream>   //iostream

using namespace std;

struct node{

    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int data;
};


void add(node *p,int sayi){

    if(p==NULL){
        p=new node();
        p->data=sayi;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;

    }
    else if(p->data>=sayi){
            add(p->left,sayi);  
    }
    else    {
            add(p->right,sayi);
    }

}

void postorder(node *p)
{

if(p!=NULL)

    {
        if(p->left!=NULL)
            postorder(p->left);
        if(p->right!=NULL)
            postorder(p->right);
        cout<< p->data<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"hata"<<endl;

    }
}

  void main(){

    struct node *k=NULL ;
    int sayi=0;

    while(sayi!=-1){
    cout<<"Bir sayi giriniz...";
    cin>>sayi;
    add(k,sayi);
    }
    postorder(k);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `sayi` in the loop in `main`? And what's your output?

Comment: I want to get the number of users and I create bst.  sayi mean number.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete` all of those `new` `node`s!

Comment: Five upvotes? Seriously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `struct node *k` by value. Whenever you change it in a function (like in `add`) it only changes the local copy (in a function), so you get back a `NULL` pointer. Pass it by reference or pointer:

```
void add(node* &p,int sayi)
{
     ...
}

struct node *k = 0;
...
add(k);
```

or

```
void add(node** p,int sayi)
{
     ... 
}

struct node *k = 0;
...
add(&k);
```

Comment: Do you have another solution

Comment: Passing by reference is the simplest solution. Why do you want another, @user1925149?

Comment: I asked for what I was wondering :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a root node to your data structure to keep track. And you will need to pass this root node reference to your `postorder()` and `add()` function call. Here `k` looks to be your root node. Declare `k` outside so that it can be accessed inside the function `add()`.

```
#include <iostream>   //iostream

using namespace std;

struct node{

    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int data;
};

struct node *k=NULL; //ROOT NODE


void add(node *p,int sayi){

    if(p==NULL){
        p=new node();
        p->data=sayi;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;
        if(k==NULL)
        k=p;  //When the first node is created, we assign it to root, i.e, k    
    }
    else if(p->data>=sayi){
            add(p->left,sayi);  
    }
    else    {
            add(p->right,sayi);
    }

}

void postorder(node *p)
{

if(p!=NULL)

    {
        if(p->left!=NULL)
            postorder(p->left);
        if(p->right!=NULL)
            postorder(p->right);
        cout<< p->data<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"hata"<<endl;

    }
}

  void main(){

    int sayi=0;

    while(sayi!=-1){
    cout<<"Bir sayi giriniz...";
    cin>>sayi;
    add(k,sayi);
    }
    postorder(k);

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code to this:

```
#include <iostream>   //iostream

using namespace std;

struct node{

    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int data;
};


node* add(node *p,int sayi){

    if(p==NULL){
        p=new node();
        p->data=sayi;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;
        return p;
    }
    else if(p->data>=sayi){
            p->left=add(p->left,sayi);  
    }
    else    {
            p->left=add(p->right,sayi);
    }
    return p;
}

void postorder(node *p)
{

if(p!=NULL)

    {
        if(p->left!=NULL)
            postorder(p->left);
        if(p->right!=NULL)
            postorder(p->right);
        cout<< p->data<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"hata"<<endl;

    }
}

int main(){

    struct node *k=NULL ;
    int sayi=0;

    while(sayi!=-1){
    cout<<"Bir sayi giriniz...";
    cin>>sayi;
    k=add(k,sayi);
    }
    postorder(k);
}
```

Comment: Thank you rondogiannis.this code sometimes incorrectly writes,but this is very good.